# `Around` with multiple errors

Tags: error-propagation, around

To my knowledge, `Around` only deals with one error. That means it can't deal with multiple sources of errors. For example, a number may have both statistic uncertainty and systematic uncertainty $s\pm \mathrm{stat.}\pm\mathrm{syst.}$. It would be convenient if `Around` can take care of this type of errors (and the error propagation). Is there any way for `Around` to do that or is there any 3rd party package for this?

Comment: how about `Fold[ Around,x , {{\[Delta]1,\[Delta]2},{ \[Gamma]1,\[Gamma]2}}]`?

Comment: @kglr I thought about that, but that would just output one error (when you actually putting numbers in there), so it won't be separated sources of errors.